# How to set up django with a postgres database in a specific tablespace?

Tags: python, django, postgresql, settings, psycopg2

What you'd expect::

settings.py

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'NAME': 'db_name',
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
        'USER': 'user',
        'PASSWORD': 'password',
        'HOST': 'host',
        'PORT': '5432',
        'DEFAULT_TABLESPACE': 'tablespace-name',
    }
}
```

When I use DEFAULT_TABLESPACE, I would expect that the access will be granted using this default tablespace. But it doesn't matter what I use there. Also, if I explicitly use db_tablespace in a models Meta class, it doesn't do anything as far I can tell.

I've tried different users as well, but even user postgres does not work. If I define db_table = "tablespace.tablename", it also does not work.

The SQL that will work:

```
select count(*) from schemaname.tablename
```

I made a backup of the database and restored it locally, without creating the tablespace. It imports well and ignores the tablespace. Then it just works.

How do I configure Django with postgres with tablespaces? Or schemaname?? Actually I don't understand anything of this, so I hope you guys can help me out.

See also: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/tablespaces/

Using Django 1.3.1, postgresql 8.4, psycopg2

Update:

It seems that the "default schema" is not picked up when using tablespaces. I tried out some tests and here are the results using ./manage.py dbshell:

This does work on my database without tablespaces, but does not work on the database with tablespaces:

```
select * from parameter;
```

This does work on both databases:

```
select * from tablespace.parameter;
```

Unfortunately, the option "DATABASE_SCHEMA" in the db settings does not work, neither does "db_schema" in the models Meta object. So the problem is a bit clearer now. Does anybody have a solution to this?

Comment: Tablespace support isn't available in Django 1.3.1. It's set to be added in the upcoming Django 1.4.

Comment: Thanks, I stopped looking for a solution and asked the owners of the database to change the tablespace :-)

Answer (score 5):

A schema and a tablespace are two different things.

A [schema](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/ddl-schemas.html) is essentially a namespace. A [tablespace](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/manage-ag-tablespaces.html) is a place in the filesystem.  Schemas are logical things; tablespaces are physical things.

If you're trying to group together a bunch of related tables (and possibly other named objects) in a namespace, you want a schema.

If you're trying to increase speed by putting indexes on a fast SSD disk--a different disk than the tables, views, etc.--you want a tablespace.